# Using launch image inside the app

Tags: ios, uiimage

How do I use the launch image in images.xcassets work inside the app?

Tried these with no luck:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "LaunchImage")!)
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "LaunchImage.png")!)
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "640x960.png")!)

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of your xcassets catalog opened in Xcode? Looks like you either refer to wrong name or it's in wrong location.

Comment: Ok, so the actual name does look ok. Are you sure that self.view is not-nil at the moment of execution?

Comment: yes i am sure it works with other images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In main bundle the Launch Images have other name representation

[image: Image assets]

You can load them using the following method:

```
UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-800-667h"];
```

Comment: this worked, however i would avoid using an if case for every screen type if i can. is there a way to let xcode decide which image to use from there? or should i explicitly write detailed names of these images in a if or switch case?

Comment: @Esq I doubt there're is any public method to get correct image name for current device and interface orientation. It is better to add special image resource for your tasks.

Comment: is there a place where i can look at these image names in detail?

Comment: As far as I know the loading images are discussed in iOS Interface guidelines, but there is no additional info about image file names there(((

Comment: @Esq as option you can observe your application bundle and investigate LaunchImage* which one is what... LaunchImage-700@2x.png is 640x960

Comment: @vorumax where exactly can i observe this from? i couldn't find it. can you explain step by step?

Comment: Archive your application and share it from the Xcode Organiser

Comment: its large and i am not on my mac atm. maybe just write something like, x->y->click on c->select b->there you go

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67719/discussion-between-voromax-and-esq).